# What test is appropriate for normality of continuos data grouped in bins

Tags: chi-squared-test, shapiro-wilk-test

I have a data set of continuous data.
From 1000 observations, the resulting dataset is only 29 rows and two columns: the range (starting point) and the count.

[Pearson - Weldon crabs dataset](https://rdrr.io/cran/MixtureInf/man/pearson.html)

| range | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5835 | 1 |
| 0.5875 | 3 |
| 0.5915 | 5 |
| 0.5955 | 2 |
| 0.5995 | 7 |
| 0.6035 | 10 |
| 0.6075 | 13 |
| 0.6115 | 19 |
| 0.6155 | 20 |
| 0.6195 | 25 |
| 0.6235 | 40 |
| 0.6275 | 31 |
| 0.6315 | 60 |
| 0.6355 | 62 |
| 0.6395 | 54 |
| 0.6435 | 74 |
| 0.6475 | 84 |
| 0.6515 | 86 |
| 0.6555 | 96 |
| 0.6595 | 85 |
| 0.6635 | 75 |
| 0.6675 | 47 |
| 0.6715 | 43 |
| 0.6755 | 24 |
| 0.6795 | 19 |
| 0.6835 | 9 |
| 0.6875 | 5 |
| 0.6915 | 0 |
| 0.6955 | 1 |

tot count = 1000
rows = 30

What test is best appropriate?

- Pearson Chi-Square
- Shapiro-Wilk

Comment: Shapiro-Wilk does not apply--and if you do apply it, it will tell you definitively the data are non-Normal, almost no matter what the counts are.  Instead, as described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919, estimate the Normal parameters using Maximum Likelihood and apply the standard chi-squared test.  BTW, if these are real data, you can see already (even without knowing what is in the remaining 24 rows) that they are non-Normal!

Comment: thanks. So I cannot apply shapiro ? Even if I add a uniform jitter in every interval to simulate number approssimations ?
(no the numbers are just garbage that I typed for example)

Comment: Adding the jitter will affect the result of Shapiro-Wilk, making its results impossible to interpret.

Comment: @whuber ok tanks,  can I use your code here? Is it appropriate ?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34882/how-to-estimate-the-third-quartile-of-binned-data/34894#34894

Comment: You need to use `nlm` instead of `optim` because there are two parameters to estimate.  You also need to take care with any low-count bins: they can screw up the chi-squared approximation.  Handle this by using `chisq.test` with its `simulate.p.value` option to perform this test once you have obtained the MLE and used that to compute the estimated bin counts.

Comment: thnaks the dataset I'm working on is the Weldon-Pearson crabs 

https://rdrr.io/cran/MixtureInf/man/pearson.html

Now I edit the question and put the real data

Comment: @whuber it's better that I consider the tails to infinite (left and right) in order to group the first two and the last two rows (with count<5)  ?

Comment: Yes: you need your bins to cover the full possible range of values.

Comment: @whuber avoiding bins with count< 5 ?

Comment: Certainly not!  You have to accommodate all the data.  When you have many bins with *expected* counts less than $5,$ the chi-squared approximation will be poor and you will need to work harder to get a correct p-value.

Comment: ok thanks, so in the dataset above I can just aggregate the low count rows in the left and right side and substitute them width two open intervals [infinite, start], [end, infinite]
Correct ?

Comment: @whuber I implemented what you suggested, check it out

https://rpubs.com/frapas/911603

Comment: @whuber I rearranged the bins, now the observed counts are [11 134 451 389  15]
and the theoretical counts are [ 4.84 127.82 506.90 326.66  33.25]
is it ok to compute Pearson Chi square Test pValue ?